# Web iframe videos start automatically

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website http://emuonline.emu.edu.tr/

In this site, there is no flag and TR top right side. When I click the link it goes to Turkish site but when the page loads, all videos play automatically. I do not want to play them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `autoplay` attribute from the video tag.

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="http://emuonline.emu.edu.tr/videos/Emu_Egitim_Videosu_Moodle.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: There is no autoplay and i do not use video tags. These videos are in the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the autoplay attribute

```
<video src="example.mp4" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
```

Comment: There is no autoplay and i do not use video tags. These videos are in the iframes.

Comment: You can try this -
<iframe>
     <video src="example.com" controls="controls">
</iframe>

Otherwise it is not possible.